# Angular data and icons are gone, but they appear again after page refresh

Tags: angularjs

I have really strange situation here. I am using Angular for my frontend. Sometimes when I open my website all drop-down input fields lose their values, icons disappear and this strange empty error appears in console. And then when I refresh website, everything returns to normal.  This usually happens when I open web page for the first time.

First time visit:

[image]

After refresh:

[image]

Note that after refresh icons are no longer gone and dropdown inputs have their values.

```
<%############################################################## OPTIONS/DATE %>
      <div class="input-dual">
        <div class="input-dual-inner">
          <span>Datum polaska:</span>
          <select ng-model="selectedYear" ng-options="year as year for year in years">
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="input-dual-inner">
          <span style="opacity: 0; cursor: default">.</span>
          <select ng-model='selectedMonth' ng-options='month as month.name for month in months'>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
```

This data is fetched from API via `$http` request.

```
// Dates
$http.get('/dates').then(function(response){
  $scope.years = response.data.years
  $scope.months = []
  for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    $scope.months.push(response.data.months[i])
  }
});
```

In short, icons and values are not present upon first time visit, and after page refresh everything works fine. How do I fix this problem?

Quicknote: First screenshot was taken after I pressed F5 that is reason for loading icon in head and loading message on bottom-left.

Quicknote 2:  First two errors are ignoreable, one is from Angular script which I didn't touch and another one even appears on Google main page.

Edit:

This screenshot shows the same problem happened in production on heroku:

[image]

Comment: I see JS errors on the first screenshot, perhaps it's related? What is the content of these errors?

Comment: @AlonEitan First two errors are ignoreable. First one says that there is code after return statement, and that is within Angular script which I didn't touch and second error appears within jQuery script which I didn't touch. Actually that second error appears on Google search website too.

Comment: My guess is that this happens because of huge load time (too much data loaded and processed at once). I am still investigating this matter and I will share update as soon as I find the issue.

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this? I am having a similar issue.

Comment: @KarlGjertsen I believe it is related to huge RAM usage while loading data. Need to load smaller chunks of data.